# Cannot bulk load because the file "\\<UC Path>\\Test.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 1240

Tags: sql, insert, bulk

I am running SQL 2014. I am trying to execute bulk insert with UNC Path and I am receiving the error below. The Script runs fine if I execute bulk insert with Local Path. Security wise, I have granted myself and Sql service account full access to the file on the remote disk.

TSQL:

```
bulk insert ExclusionList_BP from '\\Test_Server\Test.csv'with (FIELDTERMINATOR =',',rowterminator='\n' ,firstrow=2)
```

ERROR:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test, Line 33 Cannot bulk load
>   because the file "\Test_Server\Test.csv" could not be opened.
>   Operating system error code 1240(The account is not authorized to log
>   in from this station.).

Any idea would be appreciated.

Cheers
Shrestha

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid path to me - shouldn't there be a share name between the server name and the file name?

Comment: Are you able to ping 'Test_Server' from the SQL Server box ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but if someone else need it, what you need to do is to map the drive in the server, with the following command:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use \\server\shared_folder YourPassword /user:domain\YourUsername /persistent:yes'
```

To perform this you must have admin permissions over the server, if not, contact your DBA.

Once, you map the network folder, you should be able to read the file.